# how use condition in jstl

Tags: java, jstl

I have the following code:

```
<c:forEach var="pjawaban" items="${pilihanjawaban}"  varStatus="status">
    <c:choose> 
        <c:when test="${pjawaban.idPenelitian==penelitian.idPenelitian}">
            <div class="controls span9">
                <label class="radio span3">
                    <input type="radio" name="jawaban${status.count}" disabled="true" value="${pjawaban.pilihanJawaban}"/>
                    ${pjawaban.pilihanJawaban},${pjawaban.idPenelitian},${status.count}
                </label>
                <label class="span">
                    Score 
                </label>
                <label class="span">
                    <input type="text" name="nilai${status.count}" value="${pjawaban.scoreJawaban}" disabled="true"/>
                </label>
            </div>
        </c:when>

        <c:otherwise>

        </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>
</c:forEach>
```

this variable has six index, but i just want to use 4 index. I just want to count index when its condition is true, like:

```
 if(condition){
    a++;
  }else{
  }
```

Could anyone help me to implement this on jstl?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
<c:forEach var="pjawaban" items="${pilihanjawaban}"  varStatus="status">
<c:if test="${pjawaban.idPenelitian==penelitian.idPenelitian}">
    <div class="controls span9">
        <label class="radio span3">
            <input type="radio" name="jawaban${status.count}" disabled="true" value="${pjawaban.pilihanJawaban}"/>
                ${pjawaban.pilihanJawaban},${pjawaban.idPenelitian},${status.count}
            </label>
            <label class="span">
                Score 
            </label>
            <label class="span">
                <input type="text" name="nilai${status.count}" value="${pjawaban.scoreJawaban}" disabled="true"/>
        </label>
    </div>
</c:if>
```

instead of using a c:when without action in c:otherwise

Answer (score 0):

Now for your solution :

```
<c:forEach var="pjawaban" items="${pilihanjawaban}"  varStatus="status">
 <c:if test="${(pjawaban.idPenelitian eq penelitian.idPenelitian) && (status.count le 4) }">
<div class="controls span9">
    <label class="radio span3">
        <input type="radio" name="jawaban${status.count}" disabled="true" value="${pjawaban.pilihanJawaban}"/>
            ${pjawaban.pilihanJawaban},${pjawaban.idPenelitian},${status.count}
        </label>
        <label class="span">
            Score 
        </label>
        <label class="span">
            <input type="text" name="nilai${status.count}" value="${pjawaban.scoreJawaban}" disabled="true"/>
    </label>
</div>
 </c:if>
</c:foreach>
```